# month and day swap in parser library in python

Tags: python, date, parsing

I need to perform the following date type conversion in python3:

"6/11/2017 11:16:00 p.m." --> "2017-11-06 23:16:00"
I have tried with several libraries but I always get an error, even with parser that seemed to be working

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("6/11/2017 11:16:00 p.m.")
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2017-06-11 23:16:00
```

It swap day and month :(

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `dayfirst` argument -

> :param `dayfirst`:
>       Whether to interpret the first value in an ambiguous 3-integer date
>       (e.g. 01/05/09) as the day (`True`) or month (`False`). If
>       `yearfirst` is set to `True`, this distinguishes between YDM and
>       YMD. If set to `None`, this value is retrieved from the current
>       :class:`parserinfo` object (which itself defaults to `False`).

```
dt = parser.parse("6/11/2017 11:16:00 p.m.", dayfirst=True)

dt
2017-11-06 23:16:00
```

See the [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) docs for reference.